# Does AlertDialog support WebView?

Tags: android, webview, android-alertdialog

I am trying to implement a AlertDialog with a Webview inside.

```
public OnClickListener imageButtonViewOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this);

    // error here
    View alertDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_layout, null);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.DialogWebView);
    myWebView.loadData(webContent, "text/html", "utf-8");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
    builder.setView(alertDialogView);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }).show();
}
```

};

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<webView android:id="@+id/DialogWebView" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

However, I got an error at "View alertDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);" say "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class webView
" and "11-26 17:15:47.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4699): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.webView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43457e60
"

Can anyone knows whats happened? Does AlertDialog support WebView? Thank you for any advice in advance.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: myWebView is always null at "WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.DialogWebView);". I still need help ~~ Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to write **WebView**, not **webView**. Uppercase **W**

Comment: Hi ened, thank you for your reply. I corrected w to W. But myWebView is always null at "WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.DialogWebView);".

Comment: You need to use `alertDialogView.findViewById` to get it.